# How to dynamically read database columns in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

background first: I have the following agent types: *activity* and *pathway*. *pathways* are agents that contain populations of *activities*. *activities* contain specific instructions given to other agents (orders). And *pathways* are collections of those instructions.
The *pathway* collections are defined via a database where each row is 1 pathway agent & each column is the String ID of an *activity*, with the cell value being 0, 1, 2 etc depending on number of each *activity* allocated to that pathway.

Goal: I need to create a population of *activities* within the *pathway* agent at agent startup

What I have tried:
I have created a population of *activities* in Main. Each *pathway* has an *activityList* which contains the string ID of all the activities. The intention is when a cell value is 1 or above, the code would pick the corresponding *activity* agent from main and place it into the population in *pathway*. Code below, I noticed from other posts an index is used to go through rows, but this does not seem to work for columns.

Problem: I cannot get the code to search the columns dynamically, based on the list of string IDs

```
activityIndex = 0;
// there are 115 activities in the list, the code would repeat for each one
while (activityIndex <= 114)
{
    activityName = activityList.get(activityIndex);
// search below returns the cell value from row with pathway ID = agAssess
// it searches the column with string ID matching activityName
// note: error returned as the database does not contain a column named "activityName"
// in this case "activityName" in the search below would need to be replaced with the parameter's value
// error message: activityName cannot be resolved or is not a field
    double value = selectFrom(activity_groups_assess).
        where(activity_groups_assess.code.eq(agAssess)).
        uniqueResult(activity_groups_assess.activityName);
// if the value > 0, create agent with string ID activityName
// for agents with value > 1, multiple agents with the same string ID would be created, hence while function
    while (value > 0)
    {
// find the agent with the same string ID
        Activity newActivity = findFirst(main.activities, p -> p.code == activityName);
// add agent to population activitiesAssess
// error when adding agent: Description: The method add_activitiesAssess() in the type ClinicalPathway is not applicable for the arguments (Activity).
        add_activitiesAssess( newActivity );
        value--;
    }
    activityIndex++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could I clarify first, so what you have is a table that looks like this:

| Pathway id | Activity 1 | Activity 2 | Activity 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| one | 0 | 3 | 2 |
| two | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| three | 1 | 1 | 0 |

And you'd like to create 3 'Activity 2' and 2 'Activity 3' agent in Path 'one' agent. Is that correct?

If so, I am afraid there isn't a clean way to do it 'out-of-the-box'. I would suggest reading one row at a time and then calling 'add_activity'. So code looks something like the below.

```java
List<Tuple> records = selectFrom(testdbtable).list();
records.forEach(rec -> {
    String pathway = rec.get(testdbtable.pathway);
    testdbtable.getColumns().forEach(col -> {
        String activityName = col.getMetadata().getName(); // <-  this is the column name which in your case is Activity Id
        if (!activityName.equalsIgnoreCase(testdbtable.pathway.getMetadata().getName())) {
            int activityCount = (int)rec.get(col);
            // ... and below you add Acitivity agent to Pathway agent
            traceln("Pathway [%s], Activity [%s] -> count is %d", pathway, activityName, activityCount); 
        }
    });
});
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
Pathway [one], Activity [activity1] -> count is 0
Pathway [one], Activity [activity2] -> count is 3
Pathway [one], Activity [activity3] -> count is 2
Pathway [one], Activity [al_id] -> count is 0
Pathway [two], Activity [activity1] -> count is 1
Pathway [two], Activity [activity2] -> count is 0
Pathway [two], Activity [activity3] -> count is 1
Pathway [two], Activity [al_id] -> count is 1
Pathway [three], Activity [activity1] -> count is 1
Pathway [three], Activity [activity2] -> count is 1
Pathway [three], Activity [activity3] -> count is 0
Pathway [three], Activity [al_id] -> count is 2
```

So you just need add your code for creating appropriate Activity agents after the `traceln` statement. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes pretty much that, many thanks. So if the value is 3 in the cell for column 'Activity 1', then the code would create 3no. 'Activity 1' agents in 'Path One'. If the value is 1 in the cell for 'Activity N' then the code would create 1no. agents in 'Path One'. And if the value is 0, then no agents would be created. You are correct in assuming that there would be a variable number of activities as well.

Comment: sorry, i had to edit up the code a bit so the answer is updated.

Comment: Thanks for this, annoyingly I cannot paste the code in here again because it's too long. Q1: the code is placed in pathway agent, so no need to search through all the rows, how can I ref the pathway agent? Q2: what does `(!activityName.equalsIgnoreCase("pathwayid"))` this do? Because the if condition should be triggered only if cell value > 0, not by match with pathway ID Q3: should clarify there are multiple activity populations. How do I add an agent located in main.activityDatabase pop to the pathway.activitiesAssess  pop?

Comment: I included the updated code I used in the main post above for clarity. V1 is based on yours, V2 is a rewrite of how I think it should look. Thoughts?

Comment: To answer your questions - Q1: usually you can reference the agent from inside itself using 'this' keyword. But if you have a property called, for example, 'pathwayId' you can just reference that directly without 'this'; Q2: this condition skips the column in the row which has pathway id and only looks at all other columns; Q3: answer depends. do you have 114 populations each for a specific Activity Agent type? That might be excessive.

Comment: There are 3 populations and each have a corresponding table, therefore agents from Table 1 would need to be added to Population 1 in Pathway. Based on your code above I am getting the following errors: `String activityName = c.getMetadata().getName(); ` is getting error "The field Agent.c is not visible." And for `int count = r.get(c);` I am getting "The type r is not visible."

Comment: Ah yes, I should have been more diligent with names. For `c`, it is relevant in this line: `testdbtable.getColumns().forEach(c -> ...` but you can use any name, not just `c`; same with `r`, it is named from `records.forEach(r -> {...` but you can use any name.

Comment: I have updated example table, code and added example outputs in my original answer. This compiles and runs without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

You can store a reference to a database table in a variable by using the following type:

`com.mysema.query.sql.RelationalPathBase`

When selecting values of double (int, String, etc.) type in a particular column, you may get the column by index calling `variable.getColumns().get(index)`. Then you need to cast it to the corresponding type like below:

`List<Double> resultRows =  selectFrom(variable).where(`
`( (com.mysema.query.types.path.NumberPath<Double>) variable.getColumns().get(1) ).eq(2.0))`
`.list(( (com.mysema.query.types.path.NumberPath<Double>) variable.getColumns().get(1) ));`

Comment: Thanks I explored this same solution which I found in another SOF post, but it does not really resolve the issue. The code needs to return the value of the cell for that particular column, not a list of columns that satisfy the variable. If the value > 0, then I add that agent with the same ID as the column to the population. But the value could be 1, 2, 3, etc so would need to create multiple agents with the same ID. Also, not entirely clear how I could convert from type com.mysema.query.sql.RelationalPathBase to String to compare the ID of the agent with the title of the column